# Connectivity issue in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Android studio is not able to access internet on normal network from mobile Hostspot or Wifi but working fine on proxy network (college Wifi).

Tried with "No Proxy" box checked, But failed.

Comment: Did u turn off  proxy in setting of your computer? it belows the ethernet and wifi setting